# Resolve/reject fazem papel de return no javascript?

Tags: javascript, promises

Como mencionado no título, o resolve e reject de uma promise ja "fazem papel" de return ou ainda sim (dependendo da ocasião) eu preciso usar o return?

Explicando com código, eu poderia fazer desses dois jeitos:

```
//Retorna os ids dos produtos da aplicação!
function getProducts() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        fetch("/api/catalog_system/pub/products/search?fq=productId:" + dataLayer[0].productId).then(function (response) {
            return response.json()
        }).then(function (res) {
            if (!res || res.length <= 0) resolve(null)
            else resolve([dataLayer[0].productId, res[0]["Compre Junto"][0]])
        }).catch(function (error) {
            reject(error);
        })
    })
}
```

---

```
//Retorna os ids dos produtos da aplicação!
function getProducts() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        fetch("/api/catalog_system/pub/products/search?fq=productId:" + dataLayer[0].productId).then(function (response) {
            return response.json()
        }).then(function (res) {
            if (!res || res.length <= 0) return resolve(null)
            else return resolve([dataLayer[0].productId, res[0]["Compre Junto"][0]])
        }).catch(function (error) {
            return reject(error);
        })
    })
}
```

Os dois funcionam, porém, não sei se devo ou não utilizar o return, se isso influenciaria em alguma coisa... Alguém pode explicar?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

A única diferença é que quando você utiliza return no resolve/reject você inibe a execução dos demais códigos abaixo da chamada do  resolve/reject dentro do corpo da Promises.

Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```js
function promises1(param){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      if(param){
         resolve('ok - promises1');
         console.log("execução continuada após resolver promises1");
      }else{
        reject('erro - promises1');
      }
  })
}

function promises2(param){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      if(param){
        return resolve('ok - promises2');
         
         console.log("execução não continuada após resolver promises2");
      }else{
        reject('erro - promises2');
      }
  })
}

 promises1(true)
   .then(function(mensagem){
      console.log(mensagem)
   })
   .catch(function(mensagem){
      console.log(mensagem)
   });
   
promises2(true)
   .then(function(mensagem){
      console.log(mensagem)
   })
   .catch(function(mensagem){
      console.log(mensagem)
   });
```